# Dynamic Data List Definition/Form Template Javascript

Tags: javascript, liferay-6

Is there any way to add Javascript to the Dynamic Data List Definition or Form Template?

For example, if I wanted to preform a JS function such as show/hide a DDL form input depending on the selection value of another input, is this possible using Javascript in a DDL?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is possible.

Comment: If it is possible, do you have an example of how this can be done in the UI? I am looking to only add this through the UI in out-of-box liferay (through DDLS). I have yet to find a way to do this.

Comment: @KyleNeedham Any updates on this folks?